# sort strings based on a character contained in the string

Tags: perl

I have a text file containing a list of strings that I want to sort based on the first number contained within the string.  If the string does not contain a number, then ignore.

For example:

```
string1
string2
another_string1
another_string2
```

I want to sort the above to:

```
string1
another_string1
string2
another_string2
```

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried something? What?

Comment: no, it is not homework.  This is for a list of filenames that I want to run in the order I want to have sorted.

Comment: why does string1 come before another_string1 instead of after?

Comment: if the strings contain the same number, then their order with respect to each other does not matter.  I just want all the 1's to be before all the 2's, etc.

Comment: There are several examples of this very question in [perldoc -f sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/sort.html) actually.

Comment: A question to clarify:  When you say "If the string does not contain a number, then ignore.", do you mean to exclude it from the search results, or do you mean to not worry about where it ends up in the search results?  If it's the latter, wouldn't you prefer if strings with no numbers appear either at the top or bottom of the sorted list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@strings = qw/
    string1
    string2
    another_string1
    another_string2
/;
my @sorted_strings =
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map { /(\d+)/ ? [ $_, $1 ] : () }
    @strings;
```

Comment: +1: beautiful, compact solution! (perhaps, you want to match with `/(\d+$)/`, otherwise you mess up ordering for strings like `another_str1ing3`.

Comment: +1 for a canonical use of a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: @MarcoS: the question explictly said the first number in the string

Comment: you're right! (Although it seems strange to me). In this case your regex is correct :) (I've changed my code)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @strings = qw/
    string1
    string2
    another_string1
    another_string2
/;

my %h;

foreach my $string (@strings) {
    if ($string =~ /(\d+)/) {
        push @{$h{$1}}, $string;
    } else {
        print "cannot classify $string : skipping\n";
    }
}

foreach my $key (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h) {
    foreach my $s (@{$h{$key}}) {
        print $s . "\n";
    }
}
```

More verbose than [ysth's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753436/sort-strings-based-on-a-character-contained-in-the-string/5753564#5753564), but I hope it helps. Essentially: I use a hash `%h`, where keys are numbers (matched from the end of your strings), and values are arrays containing the strings ending with that number. After having constructed the hash, I print its content sorting the keys (i.e. the numbers at the end of your strings).

Comment: You want a numeric sort: `sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h`