# Sort lines of file based on a pattern in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, sed

I have a file containing the following lines:

```
This test took 1201ms to execute
The IO operation cost 113ms
Main thread have been executing for 16347ms
```

How can I sort them by the number next to `ms`?

I used the following `sed` command but did not work

```
sed -r 's/[[:digit]]\+ms//g' file.txt | sort -r | > tmp
```

Comment: There is no consistency. Whats your plan?

Comment: @heemayl I have to sort lines by ms value.

Comment: The sed command (which should be `'s/[[:digit:]]\+ms//g'` for what it's worth) is actually removing the duration value from the line, so it's doing the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Google Schwatrzian transform.

Comment: for perl solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753436/sort-strings-based-on-a-character-contained-in-the-string and https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{match($0,/[[:digit:]]+ms/,a)}{print substr(a[0], 1, length(a[0])-2),$0}' inputFile | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- -d ' '
The IO operation cost 113ms
This test took 1201ms to execute
Main thread have been executing for 16347ms
```

`awk` matches the `[[:digit:]]ms` and prints it (except the last two characters `ms`) to the beginning of the line, and `sort` using the first field. `cut` later removes the first field and gets the original line back.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} \
        {idx=gensub(".*\\s+([0-9]+).*", "\\1", "g"); arr[idx]=$0} \
          END{for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' file.txt
```

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"` variable sets the (associative) array sorting order based in numeric index
- `{idx=gensub(".*\\s+([0-9]+).*", "\\1", "g"); arr[idx]=$0}` gets the digits and make them indexes of associative array `arr` with values being the corresponding records
- `END{for (i in arr) print arr[i]}` prints the array values

If you want to reverse the sorting order to descending, do:

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
This test took 1201ms to execute
The IO operation cost 113ms
Main thread have been executing for 16347ms

% awk 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"} {idx=gensub(".*\\s+([0-9]+).*", "\\1", "g"); arr[idx]=$0} END{for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' file.txt
The IO operation cost 113ms
This test took 1201ms to execute
Main thread have been executing for 16347ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk (gawk):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/ms$/){a[$0]=$i+0; break}} END{for (line in a)print line}' file.txt
The IO operation cost 113ms
This test took 1201ms to execute
Main thread have been executing for 16347ms
```

### How it works

- `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"}`

  This tells awk to sort arrays in ascending order by array value.   This is a GNU feature.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/ms$/){a[$0]=$i+0; break}`

  For each field in a line, we see if it ends in `ms`.  If it does we assign to associative array `a` the value of the that field under a key equal to the whole line.
- `END{for (line in a)print line}`

  After we have read the whole file, we print out the keys of array `a`.  Since array `a` is sorted in ascending order by value, this print out is done in ascending order by time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to extract the numeric portion and place it at the beginning of the line with a delimiter and then `sort` it by the first field, and the use `cut` to remove the added field:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*) ([[:digit:]]+)ms(.*)$/\2|\1 \2ms\3/' file | # extract ms and place it at the beginning
  sort -t '|' -k1,1n |                                      # sort it by the field added above
  cut -f2- -d '|'                                           # remove the field
```

Output:

```
The IO operation cost 113ms
This test took 1201ms  to execute
Main thread have been executing for 16347ms
```